# Normalizar pagos de cuotas mensuales

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando en un sistema para controlar pagos mensuales (parecido a un sistema de pago de colegiatura), y estoy enredado respecto a la normalización. Por ejemplo:

**Tabla cuotas**

```
Id_abonado  id_recibo    año      mes   valorcuota pagado
12          1            2016    Enero      100        80
13          1            2016    Enero      100       100
14          2            2016    Enero      100       100
```

Y si tuviera 500 abonados, `año` y `mes` se repetiría 500 veces y dudo que esto sea correcto. Pensaba en crear otra tabla que tuviera solo el año y el mes para hacer referencia pero no estoy seguro. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizar más allí no tiene mucho sentido en mi opinión, porque `año` y `mes` son constantes que no cambiarán en un futuro. Aunque normalices y saques `año` y `mes` será prácticamente lo mismo a como lo tienes ahora. Es más, si tienes muchos registros, ese `JOIN` a esa tabla extra te costarían un poco de tiempo más en resolverse la consulta.

Lo que haría yo es un par de índices para mejorar el tiempo al consultar por dichos campos.

Comment: gracias por responder, sería más eficiente si, en vez de las columnas años y mes utilizo un campo del tipo Date para saber que cuota estan pagando? por ejemplo 01-01-2016, 01-02-2016.

Comment: Claro porque estarías redundando. Un `Date` o un `Datetime` si también te interesa la hora.